# EOF error python 3

Tags: python, eof

```
def reverse_number(x):
    return x[::-1]


number_of_sums = int(input())

for i in range(number_of_sums):
    s1 = input().split()
    print(int(reverse_number(s1[0])) + int(reverse_number(s1[1])))
```

I have the following code, which should be a solution to a SPOJ problem. It compiles fine and works for examples that I provide, but as soon as I submit it says that it found an EOF error.

It points me to line 5 in the code, and I believe I understand why. When I use input() I try to get the whole line, right? So, how would I go ahead to only get the number? If that is the problem of course, it might be something else that ruins the code.

Comment: @VanPeer, yes. I even say so in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def reverse_number(x):
    return x[::-1]

try:
    number_of_sums = int(input())
    for i in range(number_of_sums):
        s1 = input().split()
        if len(s1) > 0:
            print(int(reverse_number(s1[0])) + int(reverse_number(s1[1])))
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

Now, if you run the program and submit it will throw error stating "Invalid Input". Apart from adding the `try` block, also included the condition check for `s1` as you might encounter an "Index out of range" error if not given proper input.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the grader/engine that checks the code is running Python2, in which case you could change to:

```
number_of_sums = int(raw_input())
```

before submitting (and a similar change on line 8).

Comment: It says the compiler is 3.4, but my compiler is python 3.5 I believe. Would that make a difference?

Comment: No, that shouldn't cause it.  Sorry, I thought it might be an easy one.